# How to assemble frame fragments

Tags: kotlin, websocket, ktor

I'm using a raw session (for more overall control), and want to know how to assemble "fragments". I can't find any documents.

Comment: Hi! Please, be more specific and add some code you wrote to resolve what you want to do. Read also [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's important to ask, but it's also important to help people help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, frame reassembling is a part of the default implementation that is disabled in the raw mode.

The good thing is that it's not that hard to write frame assembling, see [the corresponding place in ktor](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/1.4.3/ktor-http/ktor-http-cio/jvm/src/io/ktor/http/cio/websocket/DefaultWebSocketSessionImpl.kt#L90)